# Rails Mailer - fallback to default 'from'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to set a mailer to be sent from a specific email address depending on some logic.

if the logic fails, I want to fallback to the default email, and keeping it DRY

```
class myMailer  < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "somespecial@email.com"


def special_send

if (logic)
 from = "noone special"
else
# set it as the default
end

mail(to: ..., subject: ..., from: from)

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ( not tested )

```
def special_send

if (logic)
   mail_hash = {to: ..., subject: ..., from: from}
else
   mail_hash = {to: ..., subject: ...}
end

mail(mail_hash)

end
```

another solution

```
def special_send
   mail_hash = {to: ..., subject: ..., from: from}    
   mail_hash.delete(:from) unless (logic)
   mail(mail_hash)
end
```

Comment: this is the last resort, since it might have a lot of duplicate data. Is there a way to set the from field to something that rails will know to use the default?

Comment: If you check the mail function at [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb) it overrides the defaults hash with values you pass using the ruby merge function so no checks are made if you pass a value.

Comment: From [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-merge)docs..Returns a new hash containing the contents of other_hash and the contents of hsh. If no block is specified, the value for entries with duplicate keys will be that of other_hash. Otherwise the value for each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key, its value in hsh and its value in other_hash.

Comment: hmph, so `nil` is not nothing after all